# Angular multi field validation async AbstractControl groupForm

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to validate that a component is valid. The definition of a valid component is that the component brand, designation, type, reference, supplierId and familyId are unique. The issues that I when de brand, designation, type, reference, supplierId and familyId are not unique and I am in the editing the field type for example but than change reference to something else in the component will still not be valid until I change the field reference. How can I fix this problem Thank you for your help.

Here is my form

```
  this.componentDetailForm = new FormGroup({
    familyId: new FormControl(0, {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)],
      asyncValidators: [this.uniqueComponentValidator.bind(this)]
    }),
    brand: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [this.uniqueComponentValidator.bind(this)]
    }),
    type: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [this.uniqueComponentValidator.bind(this)]
    }),
    designation: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [this.uniqueComponentValidator.bind(this)]
    }),
    case: new FormControl(''),
    reference: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [this.uniqueComponentValidator.bind(this)]
    }),
    voltage: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    amperage: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    power: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    supplierId: new FormControl(0, {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)],
      asyncValidators: [this.uniqueComponentValidator.bind(this)]
    }),
    price: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    minimumQuantity: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
  })
```

Here is my validator code

```
  private uniqueComponentValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {

    this.getFormValidationErrors();
    this.component.brand = this.fc.brand.value;
    this.component.designation = this.fc.designation.value;
    this.component.type =  this.fc.type.value;
    this.component.reference = this.fc.reference.value;
    this.component.supplierId = Number(this.fc.supplierId.value);
    this.component.familyId = Number(this.fc.familyId.value);

    return this.componentService.checkComponentIsUnique(this.component).pipe(map((data) => !data ? ({ componentExists: data }) : null));
  }
```

Here is a visual representation of the problem. Lets say I change the Tipo (Type) last then the form is not valid as the brand, designation, type, reference, supplierId and familyId are not unique. But then lets say I change the referencia (Reference) the component should be valid but it is not since the last field to be changed was the tipo (type)

[image: Field not valid]

[image: Fields not valid when change different field than the last one]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear and without some playground to test it, I can't really answer you. So I am going to give you some pieces of informations that might help.

A FormControl can be updated on several hooks called FormHooks. You can find them in the documentation :

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateOn

Also, a FormControl has 3 validation states : valid (all validators have passed), invalid (at least one validator has not passed), and pending (async validators are being checked).

Finally, async validators update their form controls without changing memory references, which might not trigger change detection. This is even worse with the "OnPush" strategy. Here is an exemple of the issue :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-paseta?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Hope all this helps !

Comment: I have added images of the problem does this help for the understating of the problem?